# Spring Data JPA: incorrect integer value when column's type is string

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm beginner with Spring Data JPA. When I tried to insert data into database it throw such error:

```
Incorrect integer value: 'Minister' for column 'person' at row 1
```

But it's strange because the type for 'person' in my entity class is String. I tried to find solution for my problem but I couldn't.

It's my entity:

```
package com.KingdomGame.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String person;
    @Column(unique = true, length = 1000)
    private String question;
    @Column(length = 1000)
    private String answer1;
    @Column(length = 1000)
    private String result1;
    private int impactBudget1;
    private int impactPeople1;
    private int impactPartners1;
    @Column(length = 1000)
    private String answer2;
    @Column(length = 1000)
    private String result2;
    private int impactBudget2;
    private int impactPeople2;
    private int impactPartners2;

    public Task() {
    }

    public Task(String person, String question, String answer1, String result1, int impactBudget1,
                int impactPeople1, int impactPartners1, String answer2, String result2,
                int impactBudget2, int impactPeople2, int impactPartners2) {
        this.person = person;
        this.question = question;
        this.answer1 = answer1;
        this.result1 = result1;
        this.impactBudget1 = impactBudget1;
        this.impactPeople1 = impactPeople1;
        this.impactPartners1 = impactPartners1;
        this.answer2 = answer2;
        this.result2 = result2;
        this.impactBudget2 = impactBudget2;
        this.impactPeople2 = impactPeople2;
        this.impactPartners2 = impactPartners2;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public String getAnswer1() {
        return answer1;
    }

    public void setAnswer1(String answer1) {
        this.answer1 = answer1;
    }

    public int getImpactBudget1() {
        return impactBudget1;
    }

    public void setImpactBudget1(int impactBudget1) {
        this.impactBudget1 = impactBudget1;
    }

    public int getImpactPeople1() {
        return impactPeople1;
    }

    public void setImpactPeople1(int impactPeople1) {
        this.impactPeople1 = impactPeople1;
    }

    public int getImpactPartners1() {
        return impactPartners1;
    }

    public void setImpactPartners1(int impactPartners1) {
        this.impactPartners1 = impactPartners1;
    }

    public String getAnswer2() {
        return answer2;
    }

    public void setAnswer2(String answer2) {
        this.answer2 = answer2;
    }

    public int getImpactBudget2() {
        return impactBudget2;
    }

    public void setImpactBudget2(int impactBudget2) {
        this.impactBudget2 = impactBudget2;
    }

    public int getImpactPeople2() {
        return impactPeople2;
    }

    public void setImpactPeople2(int impactPeople2) {
        this.impactPeople2 = impactPeople2;
    }

    public int getImpactPartners2() {
        return impactPartners2;
    }

    public void setImpactPartners2(int impactPartners2) {
        this.impactPartners2 = impactPartners2;
    }

    public String getResult1() {
        return result1;
    }

    public void setResult1(String result1) {
        this.result1 = result1;
    }

    public String getResult2() {
        return result2;
    }

    public void setResult2(String result2) {
        this.result2 = result2;
    }

    public String getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(String person) {
        this.person = person;
    }
}
```

It's part of code where data is inserted into relative table:

```
package com.KingdomGame.model;

import com.KingdomGame.entity.Event;
import com.KingdomGame.entity.Result;
import com.KingdomGame.entity.Task;
import com.KingdomGame.exception.NameExistException;
import com.KingdomGame.service.serviceImpl.EventServiceImpl;
import com.KingdomGame.service.serviceImpl.ResultServiceImpl;
import com.KingdomGame.service.serviceImpl.TaskServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

@Component("admin")
public class Admin {
    private String name;
    @Autowired
    private TaskServiceImpl taskService;
    @Autowired
    private EventServiceImpl eventService;
    @Autowired
    private ResultServiceImpl resultService;
    private Task task;
    private int budgetIndicator = 1000;
    private int peopleIndicator = 50;
    private int partnersIndicator = 50;

    public void setName(String name) throws NameExistException {
        List<Result> results = resultService.getAllResults();
        for (var r: results){
            if (r.getName().equals(name)) throw new NameExistException();
        }
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setData(){
        Task task1 = new Task("Minister finance","Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3", 10,-10,0, "Text 4", "Text 4",0,5,0);
```

The stack-trace of the error is next:

```
2022-08-16 21:55:11.618  INFO 10221 --- [  restartedMain] c.r.KingdomGame.KingdomGameApplication   : Starting KingdomGameApplication using Java 18.0.1.1 on VirtualBox with PID 10221 (/home/Desktop/KingdomGame/target/classes started by ensei in /home/Desktop/KingdomGame)
2022-08-16 21:55:11.620  INFO 10221 --- [  restartedMain] c.r.KingdomGame.KingdomGameApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-08-16 21:55:11.709  INFO 10221 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-08-16 21:55:11.709  INFO 10221 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-08-16 21:55:12.570  INFO 10221 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-08-16 21:55:12.642  INFO 10221 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 59 ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-08-16 21:55:13.418  INFO 10221 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-08-16 21:55:13.429  INFO 10221 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-08-16 21:55:13.429  INFO 10221 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
2022-08-16 21:55:13.489  INFO 10221 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-08-16 21:55:13.490  INFO 10221 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1780 ms
2022-08-16 21:55:13.547  INFO 10221 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-08-16 21:55:14.030  INFO 10221 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-08-16 21:55:14.040  INFO 10221 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kingdom_game?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true'
2022-08-16 21:55:14.236  INFO 10221 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-08-16 21:55:14.336  INFO 10221 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.10.Final
2022-08-16 21:55:14.550  INFO 10221 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-08-16 21:55:14.683  INFO 10221 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2022-08-16 21:55:15.313  INFO 10221 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-08-16 21:55:15.320  INFO 10221 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-08-16 21:55:15.719  WARN 10221 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-08-16 21:55:16.118  INFO 10221 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2022-08-16 21:55:16.151  INFO 10221 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-08-16 21:55:16.166  INFO 10221 --- [  restartedMain] c.r.KingdomGame.KingdomGameApplication   : Started KingdomGameApplication in 5.104 seconds (JVM running for 5.834)
2022-08-16 21:55:20.930  INFO 10221 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-08-16 21:55:20.930  INFO 10221 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-08-16 21:55:20.932  INFO 10221 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        task
        (answer1, answer2, impact_budget1, impact_budget2, impact_partners1, impact_partners2, impact_people1, impact_people2, person, question, result1, result2) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2022-08-16 21:55:21.006  WARN 10221 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1366, SQLState: HY000
2022-08-16 21:55:21.007 ERROR 10221 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Incorrect integer value: 'Minister finance' for column 'person' at row 1
2022-08-16 21:55:21.025 ERROR 10221 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: 'Minister finance' for column 'person' at row 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1061) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1009) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1320) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:994) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3279) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3885) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:756) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:742) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy93.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy93.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:666) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:700) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy97.saveAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.KingdomGame.service.serviceImpl.TaskServiceImpl.createTasks(TaskServiceImpl.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.KingdomGame.model.Admin.setData(Admin.java:182) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.KingdomGame.controller.MyController.info(MyController.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1070) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

I will be grateful for any idea about such strange behavior of my app:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly check data type for column "person" in DB. Then you can update your table by set to application.properties `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`

Comment: You are right, the type of "person" in DB is int. But I already have property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` in application.properties. So I just drop the table and restart my app. And the data type is correct now. Thank you! Have you any idea, why the data type was wrong at first?

Comment: Perhaps before that you had an int type and there were records in the database with the int person type, so spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update did not work.